# Are SQL Server Reader-Reader Deadlocks Possible?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, execution-plan, deadlock

We have heard of writer-writer and writer-reader deadlocks.

Is it possible to create a reader-reader deadlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lock hints, a reader can take an U or X lock, so in that case yes.  But otherwise no.

Even in SERIALIZABLE isolation level, readers don't take locks that would block other readers.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT queries take shared locks on the rows they retrieve. Shared locks may conflict exclusive locks from update/delete/insert statements. Two SELECT statements are not going to deadlock, but a SELECT can deadlock with an UPDATE.

Comment: That is not necessarily always true (first sentence). There are scenarios they take table locks ;) Isolation level serializable ;) Your statement is correct most of the time, still...

Comment: >>>There are scenarios they take table locks <<<Or do not take S-locks at all (only Sch-S, example read uncommitted)